# Where and when to check the expiration date and cancellation date of the subscription in the app?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

Good afternoon, I have a question about **InAppPurchases** Auto-Renewable Subscription.
Paid subscriptions can be cancelled at any time.

Where and when to check the expiration date (and possible cancellation date) inside the application ?
Do I need to call restoreCompletedTransactions every time in **didFinishLauchingWithOptions** to get the current date ?

Answer (score 0):

My short answer would be to do it once on the startup of the app (I am relatively sure that I read this also as a recommendation from Apple).

The long answer: it depends on how you validate the eligibility (locally or via a server) and how important it is to stop users from using/consuming what they got with their subscription.

For auto-renewable subscriptions, you do not need to call `restoreCompletedTransactions`, because the users' receipt always reflects his current eligibility.